# How to update a value only once flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to update a integer type value in firebase database on button pressed ,, but the issue is I want to update the value only once in firebase database on button pressed when user pressed button first time then update the value,, and when user pressed button 2nd or 3rd.... time then don't update the value how can I implement this in flutter?

Comment: - make widget with your button stateful if it is not one yet
- create a boolen variable in its state with default value false
- on first click change it to true
- based on this condition execute another callback for your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define one more place inside firebase
a variable of type bool becomes
when the user enters a value, you check that bool variable, and if it is true, you accept the variable entry.then you make the bool variable false and the entry is never provided again